# How to setup Svelte + Popper.js + display:none animation

Tags: animation, svelte-3, popper.js

I've created REPL with example using popper.js. So basically I trying to achieve correct positioning of dropdowns/tooltips for my application. So far popper does the trick.

But how do I do animation for in/out?

REPL here: https://svelte.dev/repl/15a2ad445a30415bbf8c7c741387cfca?version=3.24.1

Comment: Popper doesn't really do animation. You can go to some lengths to create your own but they have a library that acts as a wrapper for Popper called Tippy.js which will get you much closer to what you want to get done.

Comment: It's a question about Svelte I guess.

Comment: I think I can achieve it with listen for any div that goes from display: none to display:block

Comment: Right, you can add a CSS transition and some animation will happen. But this is definitely not a Svelte question. This is a CSS/Popper question. Popper uses the transform CSS property to position tooltips, your issue will be that most CSS animations also use the transform property and an element can only have one at a time. This is why Tippy was created to work with Popper, but you're free to reinvent the wheel if you like.